# How to reprogram not to show repeated combination?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am finding the combination numbers within 21 which can fulfill  `a*a + b*b == c*c` but I don't want to repeat the combination result. So how to reprogram it and not to show the repeated combination number

```
nums = range(1, 21)
trips = [(a, b, c) for a in nums for b in nums for c in nums if a*a + b*b == c*c]
print(trips)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to use sets and sorting to discard repeated elements:

```
nums = range(1, 21)
trips = sorted({(tuple(sorted((a, b))), c) for a in nums for b in nums for c in nums if a*a + b*b == c*c})
print(trips)
# [((3, 4), 5), ((5, 12), 13), ((6, 8), 10), ((8, 15), 17), ((9, 12), 15), ((12, 16), 20)]
```

If you want to flatten the tuples:

```
trips = [(a, b, c) for (a, b), c in trips]
```

However, the smart thing to do would be not to iterate over repeated combinations of `a` and `b`. You can do that like this:

```
nums = range(1, 21)
trips = [(a, b, c) for a in nums for b in nums[a:] for c in nums if a*a + b*b == c*c]
print(trips)
# [(3, 4, 5), (5, 12, 13), (6, 8, 10), (8, 15, 17), (9, 12, 15), (12, 16, 20)]
```

Or using itertools:

```
from itertools import combinations

nums = range(1, 21)
trips = [(a, b, c) for a, b in combinations(nums, 2) for c in nums if a*a + b*b == c*c]
print(trips)
# [(3, 4, 5), (5, 12, 13), (6, 8, 10), (8, 15, 17), (9, 12, 15), (12, 16, 20)]
```

Which is actually quite simple too.

Answer (score 1):

A longer code, but more efficient: we generate the combinations of `a` and `b` without duplicates, and use a dict to check if `a**2 + b**2` is one of the values we are looking for, which is faster than checking in a list.

```
from itertools import combinations

maxvalue = 21

roots = {x**2:x for x in range(1, maxvalue)}

solutions = []
for a, b in combinations(range(1, maxvalue), 2):
    c2 = a**2 + b**2
    if c2 in roots:
        solutions.append((a, b, roots[c2]))

print(solutions)

# [(3, 4, 5), (5, 12, 13), (6, 8, 10), (8, 15, 17), (9, 12, 15), (12, 16, 20)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Counter and then just print the items that have not duplicates as you please.

Here's a starter:

```
import collections

nums = range(1, 21)
trips = [(a, b, c) for a in nums for b in nums for c in nums if a*a + b*b == c*c]
counted_trips = collections.Counter(trips)
print(counted_trips)

# Then you can only print trips that have occurrency == 1 (unique)
for trip, occurrency in counted_trips.items():
    if occurrency == 1:
        print(trip)
```

Output:

```
Counter({(3, 4, 5): 1, (8, 6, 10): 1, (15, 8, 17): 1, (12, 5, 13): 1, (5, 12, 13): 1, (12, 16, 20): 1, (16, 12, 20): 1, (9, 12, 15): 1, (12, 9, 15): 1, (4, 3, 5): 1, (6, 8, 10): 1, (8, 15, 17): 1})

(8, 6, 10)
(15, 8, 17)
(9, 12, 15)
(16, 12, 20)
(12, 9, 15)
(8, 15, 17)
(12, 16, 20)
(4, 3, 5)
(3, 4, 5)
(12, 5, 13)
(6, 8, 10)
(5, 12, 13)
```

Answer (score 0):

just make `a`, `b`, `c` orderly, 
you can add `a<b<c` in `if`